# Contact closure input

Tags: protection, monitor, contact

I am designing a test box with an enable switch that provides 0v disabled or 5v enabled to a digital input. I also want to have an external enable switch that allows an external contact closure input at two banana jacks to enable by using a switch or relay contact. What are some good ways of protecting the external contact closure inputs from someone inadvertently inputting high voltage across them?

Comment: Consider adding a drawing/schematic of the system including building blocks and inputs/outputs. This can help us understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 100k resistor followed by protection diodes like [D1213A-04TS](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/D1213A-04TS-7/3340451) and eventually a capacitor to take in big transients.